# Get the values "from specific keys in a multidimensional array" and put in an array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a large array created by a form with repeaters so the array could be infinitely bigger. I need to:

- 1. Search though the array
- 2. Get all the values of [field_18]
- 3. Output an array with all the values ('-5', '-1', ect )

```
Array
(
[field_22] => Mid-Distance Free
[field_25] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
    )

[field_23] => Its a freestyle workout
[field_6] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [field_7] => 1
                [field_8] => 0
                [field_9] => 0
                [field_10] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [field_11] => 6
                                [field_12] => 50
                                [field_13] => jumping jacks
                                [field_14] => 
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [field_11] => 2
                                [field_12] => 20
                                [field_13] => pushups
                                [field_14] => 
                            )

                        [acfcloneindex] => Array
                            (
                                [field_11] => 1
                                [field_12] => 1
                                [field_13] => pushups
                                [field_14] => 
                            )

                    )

            )

        [acfcloneindex] => Array
            (
                [field_7] => 1
                [field_8] => 0
                [field_9] => 0
                [field_10] => Array
                    (
                        [acfcloneindex] => Array
                            (
                                [field_11] => 1
                                [field_12] => 1
                                [field_13] => pushups
                                [field_14] => 
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

[field_17] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [field_7] => 1
                [field_8] => 0
                [field_9] => 0
                [field_10] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [field_11] => 5
                                [field_12] => 100
                                [field_13] => Freestyle
                                [field_14] => Descend 1-5
                                [field_18] => 5
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [field_11] => 10
                                [field_12] => 50
                                [field_13] => Drill
                                [field_14] => Choice
                                [field_18] => 5
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [field_11] => 1
                                [field_12] => 400
                                [field_13] => Freestyle
                                [field_14] => Negative Split
                                [field_18] => -20
                            )

                        [acfcloneindex] => Array
                            (
                                [field_11] => 1
                                [field_12] => 25
                                [field_13] => Butterfly
                                [field_14] => 
                                [field_18] => 
                            )

                    )

            )

        [acfcloneindex] => Array
            (
                [field_7] => 1
                [field_8] => 0
                [field_9] => 0
                [field_10] => Array
                    (
                        [acfcloneindex] => Array
                            (
                                [field_11] => 1
                                [field_12] => 25
                                [field_13] => Butterfly
                                [field_14] => 
                                [field_18] => 
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

[field_19] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [field_7] => 1
                [field_8] => 0
                [field_9] => 1
                [field_10] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [field_11] => 20
                                [field_12] => 100
                                [field_13] => Freestyle
                                [field_14] => Hold 500 race pace
                                [field_18] => -5
                            )

                        [1361771245813] => Array
                            (
                                [field_11] => 1
                                [field_12] => 75
                                [field_13] => Butterfly
                                [field_14] => 
                                [field_18] => 
                            )

                        [acfcloneindex] => Array
                            (
                                [field_11] => 1
                                [field_12] => 125
                                [field_13] => Butterfly
                                [field_14] => 
                                [field_18] => 
                            )

                    )

            )

        [acfcloneindex] => Array
            (
                [field_7] => 
                [field_8] => 0
                [field_9] => 0
                [field_10] => Array
                    (
                        [acfcloneindex] => Array
                            (
                                [field_11] => 1
                                [field_12] => 25
                                [field_13] => Butterfly
                                [field_14] => 
                                [field_18] => 
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

[field_21] => Array
    (
        [acfcloneindex] => Array
            (
                [field_7] => 
                [field_8] => 0
                [field_9] => 0
                [field_10] => Array
                    (
                        [acfcloneindex] => Array
                            (
                                [field_11] => 
                                [field_12] => 25
                                [field_13] => Butterfly
                                [field_14] => 
                                [field_18] => 
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

)
```

I tried to go through all the keys but couldn't figure out where to go from there. This is the code i was using.

```
function array_keys_multi(array $array)
{
$keys = array();

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $keys[] = $key;

    if (is_array($array[$key])) {
        $keys = array_merge($keys, array_keys_multi($array[$key]));
    }
}

return $keys;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? SO is not a gimme the codez site, make an attempt and if you have problems then ask for help. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
function array_key_exists_r($needle, $haystack)
{
    //$result  = array();
    global $result;
    if(is_array($haystack)){
        foreach ($haystack as $key=>$v) {
            if (is_array($v)) {
                array_key_exists_r($needle, $v);
            }
            else{
                if($key == $needle){
                   $result[] = $v;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $result;
}


echo "<pre>";
print_r(array_key_exists_r("field_18", $your_array));
```

Comment: Edited the answer please check it now

Comment: Almost. This returned the same size array with the only the values of field_18 showing.

Comment: Fixed the issue try now

Comment: This worked Perfectly! Thank you so much. Spent so much time trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_walk_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php)

```
$array = array(/*some data*/);
$result = array();
$search_key = 'field_18';
array_walk_recursive($array, function($item, $key)use($search_key, &$result){
if ($search_key == $key)
  $result[]=$item;
});
$search_values = array('-5', '-1');
$result2 = array();
array_walk_recursive($array, function($item, $key)use($search_values, &$result2){
if (is_array($item) && array_intersect($item, $search_values))
  $result2[]=$item;
});
```

P.S. code not tested, just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Since your array can be very large as you claim using array_walk might be dangerous. If you are using php 5.5 you may build a simple foreach loop and yield the respective value. That way the consuming function can fetch as many entries as needed.

Comment: Can you give a link or explain _Since your array can be very large as you claim using array_walk might be dangerous_?

Comment: array_walk will not return until the whole array has been processed. If you use yield, you can have a consumer that stops after, say, 20 results.